# Issue Starting Laravel Reverb Server on Windows: Undefined Constant Error

Tags: php, laravel, windows

I've installed the Laravel [Reverb](https://laravel.com/docs/master/reverb) package on my Windows machine. The installation process completed without any errors. However, when I attempt to start the Reverb server, I encounter the following error:

`Undefined constant "Laravel\Reverb\Servers\Reverb\Console\Commands\SIGINT"`

Upon investigating, I found that this issue might be related to the PCNTL PHP extension, which apparently is not available on Windows ([PCNTL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php)).
Is there any workaround or solution to run Reverb on a Windows environment without this extension?

Edit: [A fix has been merged.](https://github.com/laravel/reverb/pull/76) For those who are experiencing the same issue, you just need to run `composer update`.

Comment: I have got the same issue.